# What statistical characteristics does each image have? (feat. noise, image entropy)

Tags: image, noise, entropy

I am a student studying image processing. I'm still lacking a lot, so I'm leaving a question here.

1. Image Noise

1-1) Is the statistical distribution of noise for each image unique?
For example, I wonder if Shotnoise usually follows a Poisson distribution, but has a unique Poisson distribution for each image.

1-2) Where can I get the code to calculate and graph the distribution of noise remaining in the image?

1-3) Is there a way to amplify the noise left in the image?

2. Image entropy

2-1) Is the image entropy that each image has unique?

2-2) What exactly is the image entropy?

2-3) What can you usually do using image entropy?

3. What is the difference between the statistical distribution of pixel values obtained through digital cameras and the statistical distribution of the part that artificially changed pixel values?

Thank you for reading so many questions!

I searched for noise and image entropy, but it was hard to get the clear answer I wanted.